# MySQL IN query with list of pairs unintended behavior

Tags: mysql

I just stumbled into a problem and I don't understand why this happens. I have a SELECT query with a WHERE part looking like this using varchar columns: (.,.) IN ((.,.),(.,.),(.,.)). The collation of my columns is latin1_german1_ci and somehow this is relevant when I use german letters like 'ä'. The problem is then that the query returns an empty result but it should select some columns.

I created a minimal SQL Fiddler example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8a0/3/0

```
CREATE TABLE PairProblem
    (`a` varchar(10), `b` varchar(10))
COLLATE = latin1_german1_ci
;
INSERT INTO PairProblem
(a,b) VALUES ('ä','c');

SELECT * FROM PairProblem
WHERE (a,b) IN (('ä','c'),('d','e'));

SELECT * FROM PairProblem
WHERE (a,b) IN (('a','c'),('d','e'));

SELECT * FROM PairProblem
WHERE (a,b) IN (('ä','c'));

SELECT * FROM PairProblem
WHERE a IN ('ä','d');
```

The first SELECT query there should in my opinion return the same as the second query, but it doesn't.

Since I don't understand why this happens, I cannot really ensure that my query which I need for a much more complex situation selects what I think it should select. So please help me understand this situation or at least how I can prevent such unintended behavior.

Comment: The first 3 queries all return the same thing in the sqlfiddle.

Comment: this is my markdown output:
...
**Query 1**:

    SELECT * FROM PairProblem
    WHERE (a,b) IN (('ä','c'),('d','e'))

**[Results][2]**:
**Query 2**:

    
    SELECT * FROM PairProblem
    WHERE (a,b) IN (('a','c'),('d','e'))

**[Results][3]**:
    | a | b |
    |---|---|
    | ä | c |
**Query 3**:

    
    SELECT * FROM PairProblem
    WHERE (a,b) IN (('ä','c'))

**[Results][4]**:
    | a | b |
    |---|---|
    | ä | c |

  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8a0/3
  [2]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8a0/3/0
  [3]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8a0/3/1
  [4]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8a0/3/2

Comment: Those are the same sqlfiddle links as in the question. What's your point?

Comment: The first three queries all return the row, the last query returns an empty result.

Comment: You can see [Results][2] is empty and [Results][3] is not empty, so they do NOT return the same thing.

Comment: Never mind, I read the sqlfiddle output wrong.

Comment: The first result is the one that's empty, it says `Record Count: 0`

Comment: Exactly, and that is what I don't understand ;)

Comment: As you can see in the sqlfiddle, no character set is specified and therefore the default character set latin1 for the collation latin1_german1_ci is used.